# Getting app to install emulator in a xamarin project without having the source code

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I have looked through the Microsoft documentation but everything seems to want you to run everything with the development code. I used a bitbar tutorial to help start my C# xamarinui test framework. I have the emulators working I just want the apk and ios apps to install as the first test. I know how to drag and drop and put the app on the phone manually. I am looking for a way to get the app to install and launch through test code or by some operation. I do not have access to the source.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the github repos, maybe there are the binaries uploaded? If not, just download the code and deploy to emulator. You dont need to debug or something.

Comment: there are many existing questions about how to install an APK on an emulator or device

Comment: Not using Xamarin Jason.

Comment: @user1622681 Do you mean publish the app and download it to install? And you have a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/uploading)?

Answer (score 0):

Only for the Android case, google for the apk, usually they are available on sites like apk pure etc. If the apk has executables for x86 inside you could install in on android simulator using just drag and drop.

For iOS this seems not possible as the installer has to be signed with appropriate profiles that only app developer has in his possession.

Comment: That is a way to install it but not through code following Xamarin.